# PHP Fatal error: Class 'Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider' not found

Tags: php, laravel

I was trying to make a post request from my website to a third party. And I wanted to test and see the result of the request so I added it as a Route::get in my web.php, I visited the url and I got this error

```
  "UserId" : "UserId",
  "Password" : "Password",
  "Identity" : "Identity",
  "Amount" : 0.0,
  "Currency" : null,
  "TransactionId" : null,
  "RedirectURL" : null,
  "PaymentType" : null,
  "MobileNo" : null,
  "Email" : null
  "UserId" : "UserId",
  "Password" : "Password",
  "Identity" : "Identity",
  "Amount" : 0.0,
  "Currency" : null,
  "TransactionId" : null,
  "RedirectURL" : null,
  "PaymentType" : null,
  "MobileNo" : null,
  "Email" : null
Error: PHP Fatal error: Class 'Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider' not found in vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Events\EventServiceProvider.php on line 8
```

I tried to do composer update, composer install, php artisan clear-compiled and  composer dump-autoload.. And I still got the same error wherever I go on the site. Even when I rerun php artisan serve...I keep getting the error without even the commands doing their job.

```
public function zainToken()
    {
        $data1 = ['UserId' => 'myid','Password' => 'mypw',
            'Identity' => 'my_identification','Amount' => 0.0, 'Currency' => 'JOD','TransactionId' => null,'RedirectURL'=> null,'PaymentType' => null,'MobileNo' => null,'Email'=>null];

        $curl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"theURlhere");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            $data1);

        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $err = curl_error($curl);

        curl_close($curl);
        if ($err) {
            echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
        } else {
            print_r(json_decode($response));
        }
    }
```

It should just echo the result of the post request...

Comment: Does that error only come in that controller? Is `theURIhere` a third party URI? If you comment out the output (the echo and the print_r), do you still get the same error?

Comment: Nope. Sadly its everywhere. I couldn't even do php artisan serve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... I solved this by deleting all of my files inside this repository and then I cloned it again.. that solved it. I'm not sure what caused this to happen... I might have edited a file without noticing but I don't think so as I've checked the git history difference and it seemed that I didn't do any of that.

Answer (score 0):

kindly check the library versions which you have install recently and your laravel version is suffering because of it.
or some library is missing in Service Provider

Comment: I forgot to add this as well: UserId" : "UserId", "Password" : "Password", "Identity" : "Identity", "Amount" : 0.0, "Currency" : null, "TransactionId" : null, "RedirectURL" : null, "PaymentType" : null, "MobileNo" : null, "Email" : null "UserId" : "UserId", "Password" : "Password", "Identity" : "Identity", "Amount" : 0.0, "Currency" : null, "TransactionId" : null, "RedirectURL" : null, "PaymentType" : null, "MobileNo" : null, "Email" : null  it gives me this error as well. I'm not sure why do I have this error here.. My data variable is different

Comment: have you keep anything required?

Comment: please check your route which your hitting and bedug

Comment: I edited it on my post way up there. I can't debug anything.. I can't open the site or do php artisan serve. I tried commenting the route of that function but its still not working ;(

Comment: check your composer.json file and tell me "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.7.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "^1.4",
        "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "~6.0",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1.0"
    },

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot. Here : 
  "php": "^7.1.3",
        "ext-bcmath": "*",
        "bjuppa/laravel-blog": "^1.0",
        "campaignmonitor/createsend-php": "^6.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
        "intervention/image": "^2.4",
        "laravel/framework": "5.6.*",
        "laravel/passport": "^7.0",
        "laravel/socialite": "^3.1",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "laravelcollective/html": "^5.4.0",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.0",
        "miroc/laravel-adminer": "^4.5",

Comment: even check app.php some libraries you using which is not install in app.php

Comment: "moontoast/math": "^1.1",
        "paypal/rest-api-sdk-php": "^1.13",
        "pda/pheanstalk": "^3.2",
        "pusher/pusher-php-server": "^3.2",
        "spatie/laravel-image-optimizer": "^1.3",
        "spatie/laravel-server-side-rendering": "^1.0",
        "unisharp/laravel-ckeditor": "^4.7",
        "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "^8.0"

Comment: vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Events\EventServiceProvider.php on line 8 - check EventServiceProvider in app.php

Comment: App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class, in app.php in providers section

Comment: I checked it. Its there. I haven't touched app.php or any other file. I just edited my controller and added that cURL function.

Comment: can you tell me what is written on EventServiceProvider.php on line 8

Comment: <?php

namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{    ---------------------- check it is as same as this

Comment: use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider; check this we are using this almost every where but path is failed to find the file

Comment: Yeh I've these.
"use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\Factory as QueueFactoryContract;

class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider"

I  even tried to go back with this in git... It still didn't work.. This is sooo weird.

Comment: try reverting recent changes and check once

Comment: I did.. I even tried git reset --hard . I still got nothing.. I searched the whole folder for the error I posted and found nothing...

thanks for helping but it seems my case is impossible to solve.

Comment: generally it happens if we are missing something to include or version is missmatching.

Comment: I tried echo "" > storage/logs/laravel.log . Still nothing -_-